# How do I render an object in react native?

Tags: arrays, api, react-native, expo

Working on pulling data from an external API (FlightStats). 
Currently the data fetch is working as it finds the childs of the parent request. Now stuck rendering through an array problem.

- Tried multiple options for the request and data source options

```
Request from API:

componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://api.flightstats.com/flex/schedules/rest/v1/json/flight/AA/100/departing/2019/3/24?appId=XXXXX&appKey=+XXXXX')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({
        request: response.request
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)    
        });
    }

Constructor:

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            request: 'carrier'
        }
    }

Render:

      <View style={Global.container}>
        <Text>{this.state.request.carrier}</Text>
          {/* //={[{ key: 'a'}, { key: 'b'}]}
          //renderItem={({item }) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>} */}
      </View>

Data result in Json

{"request":{"carrier":{"requestedCode":"AA","fsCode":"AA"},"codeType":{},"flightNumber":{"requested":"100","interpreted":"100"},"departing":true,"date":{"year":"2019","month":"3","day":"24","interpreted":"2019-03-24"},"url":"https://api.flightstats.com/flex/schedules/rest/v1/json/flight/AA/100/departing/2019/3/24"},"scheduledFlights":[{"carrierFsCode":"AA","flightNumber":"100","departureAirportFsCode":"JFK","arrivalAirportFsCode":"LHR","stops":0,"departureTerminal":"8","arrivalTerminal":"3","departureTime":"2019-03-24T19:40:00.000","arrivalTime":"2019-03-25T06:50:00.000","flightEquipmentIataCode":"77W","isCodeshare":false,"isWetlease":false,"serviceType":"J","serviceClasses":["R","F","J","Y"],"trafficRestrictions":[],"codeshares":[{"carrierFsCode":"AY","flightNumber":"4012","serviceType":"J","serviceClasses":["F","J","Y"],"trafficRestrictions":[],"referenceCode":1139031},{"carrierFsCode":"BA","flightNumber":"1511","serviceType":"J","serviceClasses":["R","F","J","Y"],"trafficRestrictions":[],"referenceCode":1250367},{"carrierFsCode":"GF","flightNumber":"6654","serviceType":"J","serviceClasses":["J","Y"],"trafficRestrictions":["Q"],"referenceCode":2204628},{"carrierFsCode":"IB","flightNumber":"4218","serviceType":"J","serviceClasses":["R","F","J","Y"],"trafficRestrictions":[],"referenceCode":2305895},{"carrierFsCode":"LY","flightNumber":"8051","serviceType":"J","serviceClasses":["F","J","Y"],"trafficRestrictions":["Q"],"referenceCode":2942513}],"referenceCode":"807-470028--"}],"appendix":{"airlines":[{"fs":"AA","iata":"AA","icao":"AAL","name":"American Airlines","phoneNumber":"08457-567-567","active":true},{"fs":"LY","iata":"LY","icao":"ELY","name":"El Al","phoneNumber":"+ 972-3-9771111","active":true},{"fs":"AY","iata":"AY","icao":"FIN","name":"Finnair","phoneNumber":"+ 358 600 140 140","active":true},{"fs":"IB","iata":"IB","icao":"IBE","name":"Iberia","phoneNumber":"1800 772 4642","active":true},{"fs":"BA","iata":"BA","icao":"BAW","name":"British Airways","phoneNumber":"1-800-AIRWAYS","active":true},{"fs":"GF","iata":"GF","icao":"GFA","name":"Gulf Air","phoneNumber":"973 17 335 777","active":true}],"airports":[{"fs":"JFK","iata":"JFK","icao":"KJFK","faa":"JFK","name":"John F. Kennedy International Airport","street1":"JFK Airport","city":"New York","cityCode":"NYC","stateCode":"NY","postalCode":"11430","countryCode":"US","countryName":"United States","regionName":"North America","timeZoneRegionName":"America/New_York","weatherZone":"NYZ178","localTime":"2019-03-24T00:55:59.327","utcOffsetHours":-4.0,"latitude":40.642335,"longitude":-73.78817,"elevationFeet":13,"classification":1,"active":true},{"fs":"LHR","iata":"LHR","icao":"EGLL","name":"London Heathrow Airport","city":"London","cityCode":"LON","stateCode":"EN","countryCode":"GB","countryName":"United Kingdom","regionName":"Europe","timeZoneRegionName":"Europe/London","localTime":"2019-03-24T04:55:59.327","utcOffsetHours":0.0,"latitude":51.469603,"longitude":-0.453566,"elevationFeet":80,"classification":1,"active":true}],"equipments":[{"iata":"77W","name":"Boeing 777-300ER","turboProp":false,"jet":true,"widebody":true,"regional":false}]}}
```

Error Message:

Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {resquestedCode, fsCode}). If you meant to render a collection of childen, use an array instead.

So this is where I am stuck. The initial fetching is working and finding the sub children. For some reason not sure why I cannot render the items or just display the results from the json.

Any help or tutorials will do.
Thanks again

Comment: Could you share this via codepen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`carrier` is an object in your JSON data and hence you cannot print it directly. If you want to print it as a string, please do this.

```
<Text>{JSON.stringify(this.state.request.carrier)}</Text>
```

If you want it to look neat, you can format it like this.

```
<Text>{JSON.stringify(this.state.request.carrier, 0, 4)}</Text>
```

Comment: thanks for the assit and working for getting results from the top section of the data
- now looking to pull the sub set of data for 'scheduledFlights'